Can't define BackgroundSocketProcessor with ASP.NET Core 8
I'm following the instruction by Microsoft but I can't use BackgroundSocketProcessor. Do I miss any library?
This is my Program.cs:
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    using var webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
    var socketFinishedTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    BackgroundSocketProcessor.AddSocket(webSocket, socketFinishedTcs);

    await socketFinishedTcs.Task;
});

I'm really confused and trying to figure out why it doesn't work

It is because in the current context, 'BackgroundSocketProcessor' has not been defined or declared, the system cannot find a corresponding definition.
So, you could create a class named BackgroundSocketProcessor to define it. Refer to the sample code provided by Microsoft.
internal class BackgroundSocketProcessor
{
    internal static void AddSocket(WebSocket webSocket, TaskCompletionSource<object> socketFinishedTcs) { }
}

